# Dynamically Mirror and Stack Columns from multiple Sheets containing the same headers into Master Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am wondering if what I am trying to accomplish is possible. I have several different sheets containing the same column headers. These sheets may contain a different amount of rows, and will have rows added or deleted periodically.

I am wondering if it is possible with a formula or other method to mirror the columns of each different sheet into one master sheet containing the same headers. And then dynamically stack the rows so there are no blank rows in between.

I have tried using a Microsoft Query to no avail. I am only able to get one sheets worth of data that way, or end up with a duplicate set of columns per sheet I am trying to mirror.

Comment: You will need to program something in vba in a worksheet_change event that redraws the master sheet every time the other sheets change.  Formulas are really not designed for things like this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.